# How to get a confirmation that my BahnCard has been cancelled?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

I requested to cancel my bahn card using [this](https://www.bahn.com/en/view/home/info/cancel-bahncard.shtml) form.  I am currently living in the USA. I received an email three weeks ago stating that my request has been forwarded to the appropriate department and I will get confirmation from them. I have not heard from them yet, but last week I got another email (now in German), and it is asking me to rate their service I recently used (i.e. canceling my card). I am not sure if my card is canceled or not, how can I be confirmed about that? Should I do anything else?

Thanks

Comment: Just try to book a fully refundable ticket and put in your BC card number during check out. If it gets through, it's still active

Comment: @Himar If the previous card is still active (which it should be if the OP is trying to cancel his BahnCard subscription on time), this should work even if the subscription has been cancelled.

Comment: @Himar If the previous card is still active (which it should be if the OP is trying to cancel his BahnCard subscription on time), this should work even if the subscription has been cancelled.

Comment: @Hilmar The number is linked to an account, not a BahnCard.  E.g. you can still collect BahnBonus points with that number after your BahnCard expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if your BahnCard has been correctly canceled online:

1. Go to https://www.bahn.com/en/view/index.shtml, login with your username/password.
2. Click on "All BahnCard Services" under "My Bahncard services" approximately in the middle of the page.
3. This is where the webpage always switches to German for me. There is a menu item "Informationen zu meiner BahnCard" (Information about my Bahncard) that you can click on.
4. The page afterwards shows all the BahnCards you recently had, their validity, and *should* contain the information whether they have been canceled or not. "Abo" means "subscription". According to [this answer](https://community.bahn.de/questions/1274715-hallo-mochte-wissen-ob-bahncard-bereits-gekundigt-habe-irgendwie-nachschauen) on community.bahn.de, it says "nein" (no) below the "Abo" header if and only if you quit the subscription for your BahnCard.

Comment: I can see "nein" as stated.